# Disable LEDs Pi Zero

Tags: led, pi-zero

Can I disable the yellow (PWR?) LED on the Pi Zero?

I've tried setting the brightness to `0` of `led1` (it starts life as `255`) and `led0` is already `0` but I still get the LED glow.

Out of interest, I only managed to set the brightness file to zero by running the following from `/etc/rc.local`

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/led1/brightness
```

Verified after booting with the following.

```
$ cat /sys/class/leds/led1/brightness
0
```

If I try as the `pi` user or even via `sudo`, I get the following error. Even after `chmod`. Any ideas why?

```
-bash: /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness: Permission denied
```

Comment: It's not  a power LED, the Pi Zero has one LED, the activity LED.

Comment: Makes sense, I can see `ACT` next to it :)

Comment: "...If I try as the pi user or even via sudo,..." I think that is a common trap where people do not realise that the redirection (of `stdout` to the `/sys/class/leds/led1/brigthness` file) occurs before the sudo command is run so it does not get the sought for privileged elevation.  There is a (somewhat *funky*) way around it with a `tee` command but I do not have the details to hand...!

Comment: Thanks. I'd tried `bash -c 'echo 0 > ...` with the same affect (it doesn't work). I can't quiet remember but I think there's a difference between true `root` (which will be the user for `rc.local` no?) and `sudo`. Anyway... I'd have to do some reading to remind myself :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following to /boot/config.txt and reboot.

```
dtparam=act_led_trigger=none
```

The LED is wired with inverse logic.

Write 1 to GPIO 47 to switch it off.

Write 0 to GPIO 47 to switch it on.

Comment: Thanks, that worked (along with running `echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness`, which I put in `rc.local`)

Comment: You may get away with also adding dtparam=act_led_activelow=on to /boot/config.txt (so you don't need the rc.local script).  It doesn't do what it should do but a side effect does seem to be the LED starts up off.

Comment: Even better! That works and keeps it all in one place. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo nano /boot/config.txt`

There is currently a [different way](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1742#issuecomment-1230978826) to achieve this on different pi models.
You may want to add [model filters](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html#model-filters) to config file as followingly:

```
#Disable Power LED (Red)
[pi3]
dtparam=pwr_led_trigger=none
[pi3+]
[pi4]
dtparam=pwr_led_trigger=default-on
[all]
dtparam=pwr_led_activelow=off

#Disable Activity LED (Green)
dtparam=act_led_trigger=none
dtparam=act_led_activelow=off
```

`sudo reboot`